# Does Javascript string.toLowerCase() follow Unicode standards in case-conversions?

Tags: javascript, string, unicode

I'm creating a browser-based form verification script that checks if the input doesn't have any uppercase characters according to Unicode Standards. My definition of an uppercase character is a character that has a lowercase mapping. If a certain character in the input string doesn't have a lowercase or uppercase mapping (like chinese characters) then it's alright (it should pass my validation).

I'm using UTF-8 encoding.

I'm planning to create a function that looks like this:

```
function hasUpper(str){
  if(str != str.toLowerCase()){
    return true
  }
  else {
    return false
  }
}
```

Will this work for my needs?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that you can simplify that function to `return str != str.toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that will work. Incidentally, the Boolean keywords are `true` and `false`, lower case. :)

Comment: I the same vein the function can be shortened to: 

    function hasUpper (str) {
      return str !== str.toLowerCase ();
    }



        Bah, no formatting in comments :-(

Comment: @Hans B PUFAL: asddYou can format by bracketing with the backwards accent character, which is the lowercase option on the tilde key (~).

Comment: not neccesarily - im the # symbol is the lowercase option on my (UK) keyboard. The backtick symbol is above the tab key.

Comment: @Nico Burns: Reminds me of Shaw's comment that England and America are two countries separated by a common language. Cheers. :)

Comment: Thanks! the Boolean keywords are in lowercase, indeed.

Answer (score 3):

The question answered here seems to indicate that toLower and toUpper are Unicode-aware:[Stack OverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929079/unicode-lowercase-characters)

And this one goes into it in more detail (indicating that some mappings conflict with the real world):[more Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154862/convert-javascript-string-to-be-all-lower-case)

Hope this helps!